# Vuejs 2 input radio's v-model not working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

[Live example](https://jsfiddle.net/mj111/my4u6Lwb/).

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <radio v-model="eventTypeInput" id="et-internal" name="event_type" 
  :selectedValue="0">internal</radio>
  <radio v-model="eventTypeInput" id="et-external" name="event_type" 
  :selectedValue="1">external</radio>
   {{eventTypeInput}}
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    radio: {
      template: `<div class="control-item">
        <input type="radio" autocomplete="off" ref="input"
          v-model="model"
          :value="selectedValue"
          :id="id"
          :name="name"
          :disabled="disabled">
        <label :for="id"><slot></slot></label>
      </div>`,
   name: 'input-radio',
   props: {
     disabled: {type: Boolean, default: false},
     name: {type: String, default: null},
     selectedValue: {default: true}, // this radio value
     value: {default: false}, // v-model variable
     id: {required: true}
   },
   computed: {
       model: {
         get () {
           return this.value
       },

       set (val) {
         this.$emit('input', val)
        }
      }
    }
   }
  },
    data () {
     return {
        eventTypeInput: 'initial value'
    }
  }
});
```

I made a radio input component that works with `v-model`.

When I click the radio element, the expression bound via `v-model` is not changing.

What am I doing wrong? Is this a Vuejs bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `selected-value` when you pass the `selectedValue` property.

```
<radio v-model="eventTypeInput" id="et-internal" name="event_type" :selected-value="0">internal</radio>
```

When properties are defined in camelCase, they need to be passed in kebab-case. This is described [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#camelCase-vs-kebab-case) in the documentation.

> HTML attributes are case-insensitive, so when using non-string templates, camelCased prop names need to use their kebab-case (hyphen-delimited) equivalents

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/my4u6Lwb/1/).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that HTML properties are case insensitive, if you change `selectedValue` with `selected_value` (for example) in every instance, it works.